# How to pass model values to a webservice which is present on the another server?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to this web service and cloud computing.

I am having a mvc4 project.
I had created a web service(ASMX) as a new project.
Now I had add the reference of that webservice to my mvc4 project.

**Please note that my MVC4 project and the webservice are both 2 different project. 
I need do the connection between the two project so that I can pass the model parameters to that webservice and get the response as-well from the webservice.**

only i have to do is to pass the model values to that Web service.

I am having no idea how to do that... ????

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use "Add Service Reference" to reference your web service the same as if it were an external service.

See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)" for details.